# C# How to check if user scrolled with mouse(up/down)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Same as in the title is there a way to check if user scrolled up/down?
This is how i check but its not working

```
Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(Form_Scroll);
void Form_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e){MessageBox.Show("Scrolled");}
```

But when i scroll i do not get the message.

Comment: Looks like you arent attaching your scroll event handler to an actual event.

Comment: @Takarii you mean i need to replace ScrollEventArgs with ScrollEventHandler?

Comment: no, i mean you need to actually attach the handler to an actual scroll event - such as a control or a form